# ngcli 6.1.3 ERROR in ./src/main.ts - Can't resolve './app/app.module.ngfactory'

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-builder

I am using angular/cli 6.1.3 and am getting an error below when trying to compile using enableIvy: true in `tsconfig.app.json`:

```
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'xxxxPath'
```

Build command:

```
ng build --prod --source-map=false --base-href='/'  --extract-css=true --delete-output-path=true --aot --build-optimizer=true
```

The version details of angular/cli

```
Angular CLI: 6.1.3
Node: 10.7.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.1.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.7.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.7.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.7.3
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.7.3
@angular-devkit/core              0.7.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.7.3
@angular/cli                      6.1.3
@ngtools/webpack                  6.1.3
@schematics/angular               0.7.3
@schematics/update                0.7.3
rxjs                              6.2.2
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.9.2
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Remove `BrowserModule` from your `app.module.ts` file, Both from the imports section of the ngModule declaratrion and the actual ES5 import at the top of the file

And modify the bootstrapping in `main.ts`:

```
import { enableProdMode, ɵrenderComponent } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppComponent } from './app/routes/app/app.component';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}


ɵrenderComponent(<any>AppComponent);
```

Main bundle went from 1.4mB to 636kB, can't wait.

Comment: Let me try that. It is great to hear the size difference.